# Translate port for two clients accessing the same resource on a remote network using pfsense

Tags: nat, pfsense

I have two client PCs which need to access the same remote resource. They are both connected to a pfsense device. The problem is, both clients try to connect to the remote device using the same port. One client gets kicked off.

Is there a way to configure pfsense so that that one of the clients will get mapped to a different port outgoing?

What I have now:

Client 1 Port 90 --- > Pfsense Port 90 --- > Remote host Port 1000

Client 2 Port 90 --- > Pfsense Port 90 --- > Remote host Port 1000

What I want:
Client 1 Port 90 ------ > Pfsense Port 90 ------ > Remote Host Port 1000

Client 2 Port 90 ------ > Pfsense Port 90 > 91 ------ > Remote Host Port 1000

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into the pfsense web interface.

Go to Firewall > Nat. Make sure "Manual Outbound NAT rule generation (Advanced Outbound NAT (AON))" is selected.

Create a new rule.

Interface : WAN

Source: Network 
        Address : IP of local machine you wish to map a differente port for. Make your                                        netmask /32
        Source Port: Enter the port the client tries to connect from (My example 90)

Destination : Leave all default

Translation : Interface Address
              Port : Port you wish to remap to (My example 91).

Save.